# Show URL (/index.php/dashboard) without PHP extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, hide

I have a running web application at my webserver. After the login dialog (login @ www.mydomain.com) you will redirect to this URL: mydomain.com/index.php/dashboard.

How can I hide the .php extension in my URL?

I tried it hard with some .htaccess settings, like "I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT I'M DOING" :D
I need your help guys!

My last .htaccess condition:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: htaccess doesn't change the URL. If the link is `/index.php/dashboard`, then that's what the browser will say. htaccess only maps a pattern to another page _internally_. What you can do is remove the index in your link and just do `/dashboard` and handle the URL in your code. Look into routers.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `.htaccess` you can achieve this using folders to structure each page.

For example your dashboard; you create folder `dashboard` in your root directory and then create an `index.php` file in that folder. The file will contain the html/php code for your dashboard. Now you can access your page as `mydomain.com/dashboard`